# GitHub Tag Triggers Multiple Travis CI Builds

Tags: git, continuous-integration, tags, travis-ci

I have one of my GitHub project integrated with Travis CI and the set up has been working so great (unfortunate that Travis CI will not be free starting next year), but nevertheless I started to do release versions for my project and for this purpose I'm tagging for releases from my master branch.

So when I want to release, I tag the master branch, bump the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH version to the appropriate level and I push the tag using:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/plant-simulator$ git tag -a v1.0.5 -m "bumbped a tag once more now"
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/plant-simulator$ git push --tags origin master
```

This is so far good, but then if I look in my Travis CI build, I see two builds are triggered:

- one for the master branch
- two for the tag version v1.0.5 in this case

and I do not want them like this. I just want that if there is a Tag tagged, I only need this tag to be built! Any idea how I could control this with my Travis YML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood why this happens. So if I want to just push the tags against my master branch that is up to date with the remote, I just issue the commands below:

```
git tag -a v2.2.2 -m "Your comments" // Create annotated tag

git push origin --tags               // Push annotated tag
```

Notice the difference between the git push command, here I omit the push to the master branch. With this I could achieve what I want. The CI server just triggers a single build for the tag.